# Vue.http.get w/ authorization - makes 2 requests and fails on iOS only

Tags: ios, vue.js, vue-resource

I have to make an authenticated HTTP request using a bearer token. This works flawlessly on everything I've tested...except *some* iOS devices.

```
  fetchWithToken : function( endpoint, token ){
    return Vue.http.get( urlBase + endpoint, {
      headers : {
        Authorization : 'Bearer ' + token
      }
    });
  },
```

From what I can tell, the request is being sent twice. Note this function only gets called once (verified by debugging) but the server receives 2 requests. The first request contains the token and authorizes successfully. The second has no token and fails, returning that failure to the rest of my app.

The two HTTP requests from one call makes me think CORS preflight requests. However it is the same domain and the urlBase variable in that function above is a relative address ('/api/'), not a full URL.

Is iOS forcing CORS? And if so, why is the second request sent without the authorization header instead of the preflight request?

Comment: Further logging of both server and front end reveals that the 2 requests are actually not CORS, but a 301 redirect. The authorization token is stripped from the second request on iOS, but not other devices. Don't have a workaround yet.

Comment: Bad combination of events. The server (a symfony app) was doing a 301 redirect for endpoints that didn't end in a slash. Apparently iOS is the only user agent that does not let the authorization header carry over on a 301 redirect. So the first request had the token, it was 301'ed, and the 2nd request did not. Basically 3 hours of logging and tracing everything down to learn I need to end my endpoint calls with a /.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bad combination of events. The server (a symfony app) was doing a 301 redirect for endpoints that didn't end in a slash. Apparently iOS is the only user agent that does not let the authorization header carry over on a 301 redirect. So the first request had the token, it was 301'ed, and the 2nd request did not. Basically 3 hours of logging and tracing everything down to learn I need to end my endpoint calls with a /.